# raise err.ProgrammingError("execute() first") pymysql.err.ProgrammingError: execute() first

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a connection function that return cursor, I am using pymysql to connect with my db, and I have another file that use the connection function to execute sql statement but when I fetch the row it return an error `raise err.ProgrammingError("execute() first")`

Here is the connection function that extend from my database config file

```
def kasaa():
    try:
        conn = mysql.connect()
        cursor = conn.cursor(pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
        return cursor
   except Exception as e:
      print(e)
```

But when I call the `kasaa()` inside an employee class that is where it raised an error of `execute()` first

```
def get_multiple_info(self,employees_ids):
    """Get info of multiple Employees in database"""
    try:
        for employee_id in employees_ids:
            kasaa().execute(
                 "SELECT * FROM ospos_employees WHERE ospos_employees.deleted = 0 AND ospos_employees.person_id = %s ",
                 employee_id
             )
            row = kasaa().fetchone()
            return row()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    finally:
        kasaa().close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code in `kasaa()` is executed twice, so `fetchone()` is actually called without `execute()`. Get the `cursor` and use it to call the other functions

```
def get_multiple_info(self, employees_ids):
    """Get info of multiple Employees in database"""
    cursor = None
    try:
        for employee_id in employees_ids:
            cursor = kasaa()
            cursor.execute(
                "SELECT * FROM ospos_employees WHERE ospos_employees.deleted = 0 AND ospos_employees.person_id = %s ",
                employee_id
            )
            row = cursor.fetchone()
            return row()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    finally:
        cursor.close()
```

Comment: i appreciate the patient. i didn't understand where does function kasaa() executed twice i have use the solution you have suggest but i still get the same result(ie the raised Error)

Comment: @AlkhadhilIssa You call `kasaa()` again in `finally`. Edited my answer.

Comment: ooooh i see where i was doing wrong i appreciate the help